# Grub2 password doesn't work

Tags: boot, grub2, password, encryption

I protected my GRUB-bootloader with an encrypted password that contained special characters. Now I'm unable to write the correct password to continue booting into the system. Does GRUB-bootloader understand all the characters available on keyboard or is there differences between grub and the system? I included even one character which requires using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

I'm running headless Ubuntu server 18.04 with `lvm2`. This is a learning project so I'm not an expert user but rather a novice.

I've already tried to fix this with the install media in live mode but then somehow I can't get my filesystem mounted to proceed in fixing it. What should I do next?

Comment: What error do you have when trying to mount the file system? How did you set up the encryption?

Comment: I did the encryption using command grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 in screen mode and then I copy/pasted the result into the end of the file located at /etc/grub.d/40_custom. I also changed the superuser name for that password and finally used the command grub2-mkconfig > /etc/grub2.cfg for it to take effect.

Comment: For the lvm part I have to try again to explain it - or maybe I can get it straight this time..

Comment: Sorry for a long wait. Now as I had time to figure out this problem, I managed to chroot in to the unusable system. I used sudo lvscan -command to find out which partition is active and then I mounted it with sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv  /mnt. Then I activated the mounted system with sudo vgchange -ay and finally chrooted it with sudo chroot /mnt.

Comment: I tried to fix the password problem by adding --unrestricted option to the /etc/grub.d/10_linux configuration file but after doing that, grub refuses to run mkconfig as it says "cannot find a device for / . Isn't it mounted as I did as I said above?